# How do I automatically cast a class instance to Float in Ruby?

Tags: ruby, casting, floating-point, proxy-classes

I have an Angle class that I want to behave like a float, with additional behavior. I have created the class to contain a float and proxy all unknown methods to it:

```
class Angle
  include Math
  def initialize(angle=0.0)
    @angle = Float(angle)

    # Normalize the angle
    @angle = @angle.modulo(PI*2)
  end

  def to_f
    @angle.to_f
  end

  # Other functionality...

  def method_missing(message, *args, &block)
    if block_given?
      @angle.public_send(message, *args, &block)
    else
      @angle.public_send(message, *args)
    end
  end
end
```

It works fine. However when I try to use it with trig operations, e.g. Math.cos, I get:

```
> a = Angle.new(0.0)
 => #<Angle:0x00000000cdb220 @angle=0.0> 
@angle=0.0
> Math.cos(a)
TypeError: can't convert Angle into Float
```

I know I can use Float(a) to convert to a float, but it's inconvenient since I want this class to behave like a float. Is there a way to automatically convert Angle to float in these cases?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looking at the [implementation of Math.cos](https://github.com/ruby/ruby/blob/trunk/math.c#L78-91), you can see it calls a macro called Need_Float, [which then calls a function rb_to_float](https://github.com/ruby/ruby/blob/trunk/math.c#L27). [Line 2441 of rb_to_float checks to see if the object passed in is of type Numeric](https://github.com/ruby/ruby/blob/trunk/object.c#L2437-2449). So it seems the only way to have your own class act as a float in the Math family of functions is to have it inherit from Numeric or a descendant of Numeric. Thus, this modification of your code works as expected:

```
class Angle < Numeric
  include Math
  def initialize(angle=0.0)
    @angle = Float(angle)

    # Normalize the angle
    @angle = @angle.modulo(PI*2)
  end

  def to_f
    @angle.to_f
  end

  # Other functionality...

  def method_missing(message, *args, &block)
    if block_given?
      @angle.public_send(message, *args, &block)
    else
      @angle.public_send(message, *args)
    end
  end
end

if __FILE__ == $0
  a = Angle.new(0.0)
  p Math.cos(a)
end
```

I'm not sure what side effects inheriting from Numeric will have, but unfortunately this looks like the only way to have your code work the way you want it to.

Comment: Couldn't Angle implement `to_float`?

Comment: I expected there to be a to_float coercion method analogous to to_ary and to_proc, but it doesn't appear ruby has one.

Comment: Interesting workaround. I'd probably need to ensure that Float methods get called instead of Numeric ones.

Comment: @phiggy: Maybe you should ask on ruby-talk or ruby-core why it doesn't try `to_float` coercion.

Answer (score 0):

This is what I came up with on my own. Math is the only module that I'm really interested in, so I can make a proxy for it:

```
module Stdlib; end
::Stdlib::Math = ::Math
module AngleMath
  # Copy constants
  Stdlib::Math.constants.each do |c|
    self.const_set(c, ::Stdlib::Math.const_get(c))
  end

  def self.map_angles_to_floats(args)
    args.map do |a|
      a.kind_of?(Angle)? a.to_f: a
    end
  end

  def self.method_missing(message, *args, &block)
    if block_given?
      ::Stdlib::Math.public_send(message, *map_angles_to_floats(args), &block)
    else
      ::Stdlib::Math.public_send(message, *map_angles_to_floats(args))
    end
  end
end
::Math = AngleMath
```

Now with the Angle class definition from above:

```
a = Angle.new(0.0)
# => #<Angle:0x00000000e6dc28 @angle=0.0> 
Math.cos(a)
# => 1.0
```